# Visual Studio : how to change color of the collapsed XML doc comment

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, textcolor

In Visual Studio, how do I change the color of the line `<summary> Gets the ...` ?

I have tried **Fonts & Colors** -> **Text Editor** ->then change the color of XML Comment, XML Doc Comment, XML Doc Tag, but it is not.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit old, but I've found the solution. Maybe it helps people like me who come across this question through Google...

Change the color of the **Collapsed Text (Collapsed)** and **restart** VS.

To find under:  Tools\Options...\Environment\Fonts and Colors (VS2019)